# EXTJS 5.0: button click event not getting fired on latest mozilla version(59.0.2)

Tags: extjs

**EXTJS version: 5.0.0.970**

**Mozilla version: 59.0.2**

**Device:** Touch screen laptop with touch configuration ON.

Button click event not getting fired on above scenario. I have not checked for other components for their events since I found this issue.
Also, If I try to perform same action by touch action then it works.
Fiddle link: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2g2o&view/editor

If anyone has any solution or any workaround please help.

Comment: I have tried on my mobile device by installing mozilla and it works, can you please try once by putting `alert('Basic Button handler');` instead of `Ext.Msg.alert('Basic Button', 'Basic Button handler');`

Comment: My question clearly tells about touchscreen laptop issue.And what does putting alert will achieve ?
And on touchscreen laptop also it works fine if i perform same operation through touch.